# Pandas "join" oddity

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge

If I try this (with two different vintages of `pandas`, one in Python 2, another in Python 3)

```
import pandas as pd
x = pd.DataFrame({"id": [1, 2,3], "value1": [5,5,5]})
y = pd.DataFrame({"id": [1], "value2": [10]})

z1 = x.join(y, on = "id")
z2 = x.join(y, on = "id", lsuffix = "_left", rsuffix = "_right")
z3 = x.join(y, lsuffix = "_left", rsuffix = "_right")
```

the first join fails with a `ValueError`, the second one does not break but `y` is not matched, and only the third join produces the expected result, i.e. `y`'s row matched up to `x`.

The doc for `join` says

> on : name, tuple/list of names, or array-like
>   Column or index level name(s) in the caller to join on the index in other, 
>   otherwise joins index-on-index. If multiple values given, the other DataFrame 
>   must have a MultiIndex. Can pass an array as the join key if it is not already
>   contained in the calling DataFrame. Like an Excel VLOOKUP operation.

Is this (i.e. what happens with `z2`) a bug, or does it somehow make sense?

Comment: why would 1 fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df.join(...)` is usually used to join on the index of `df` with the index of another DataFrame.

[`df.join(..., on='id')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) joins the `id` column of `df` with the index of another DataFrame.
[Per the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) (my emphasis):

> on : name, tuple/list of names, or array-like
>
> **Column or index level name(s) in the caller to join on the index in other**, otherwise joins index-on-index. If multiple values given, the other DataFrame must have a MultiIndex. Can pass an array as the join key if it is not already contained in the calling DataFrame. Like an Excel VLOOKUP operation

Since `x` and `y` look like this:

```
In [14]: x
Out[14]: 
   id  value1
0   1       5
1   2       5
2   3       5

In [15]: y
Out[15]: 
   id  value2
0   1      10
```

`x.join(y, on='id')` attempts to join `x['id']` (with values `1, 2, 3`) with `y.index` (with value `0`). Since **`x['id']` and `y.index` have no values in common**, the (by default) left join produces NaNs for the values in the new `y`-columns produced by the join.

---

`z1 = x.join(y, on = "id")` raises

```
ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index(['id'], dtype='object')
```

because the `y`-columns produced by the join include `id` which is already a
`x`-column name. When column names overlap, you must specify a `lsuffix`,
`rsuffix`, or both to disambiguate the column names.

---

`z2 = x.join(y, on = "id", lsuffix = "_left", rsuffix = "_right")` returns

```
In [12]: z2
Out[12]: 
   id_left  value1  id_right  value2
0        1       5       NaN     NaN
1        2       5       NaN     NaN
2        3       5       NaN     NaN
```

because the common `x` and `y`-column (i.e. the `id` column) has been disambiguated.
The `NaN` values are due to  `x['id']` and `y.index` having no values in common (as explained above).

---

`z3 = x.join(y, lsuffix = "_left", rsuffix = "_right")` produces

```
In [20]: z3
Out[20]: 
   id_left  value1  id_right  value2
0        1       5       1.0    10.0
1        2       5       NaN     NaN
2        3       5       NaN     NaN
```

because now the join is being performed on `x.index` and `y.index`.